# Django1.4 not compatible with Python3.2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, syntax-error

I installed Django1.4 on Win 7 with python3.2. But when I run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` on command prompt I get errors like Syntax error: Invalid Syntax. It shows that there is an error at `print ''.join ......`. I see that print is missing `()`. I fixed one Syntax error already.

Is it incomparability issue?

What do you suggest should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't officially support Python 3.x yet.  Use it with Python 2.7.

Here's the official latest news about Django on Python 3: https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/mar/13/py3k/

There is an unofficial experiment in supporting Python 3 with a common code base:  https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/django/

Comment: Thanks For The Quick Response.
I Am New To The Python World. And I Have Invested A Lot Of Time Learning Python3. I Think I Should Not Go With Django Till It Supports Python3. 
I Will Stick With Enhancing My Skills With Python3.

Thanks Again :)

Comment: @AashiqHussain: if you try 2.7, you will find that the differences are not large.

Comment: @AashiqHussain it might also be worth noting that the 2.x versions of Python still is the most widely used, especially for commercial purposes.

Comment: @olofom: To a large extent because many major frameworks, such as Django, doesn't support it yet. :-)

Comment: @AashiqHussain: Pyramid is a nice web framework that supports Python 3.